# Docker how to get volumes used by a container

Tags: docker

I'm using Docker version 1.10. How can I get the volumes used by a container?

I know I can get the containers by:

```
docker ps
```

And I can inspect them with:

```
docker inspect $containerID
```

I also know that the volume API is available, so I can also do:

```
docker volume ls
```

and

```
docker volume inspect $volumeID
```

But I can't find any link information between them. What should I use?

Answer (score 45):

You can get the detail volume information of a container by

```
docker inspect --format="{{.Mounts}}" $containerID
```

If I create a volume named "volumehello", and start a container named "hello" which use "volumehello":

```
docker volume create --name volumehello
docker run -it -d --name=hello -v volumehello:/tmp/data hello-world
```

Then we can get the volume information of "hello" container by running:

```
docker inspect --format="{{.Mounts}}" hello
```

We will get:

```
[{volumehello /var/lib/docker/volumes/volumehello/_data /tmp/data local z true rprivate}]
```

- **volumehello** is the volume name
- **/var/lib/docker/volumes/volumehello/_data** is the host location of the volume
- **/tmp/data** is the mapped location of the volume within the container

Comment: But what if i does not create the volume first and create it with the run command, example docker run -it -d --name=hello -v /opt:/tmp/data hello-world, it does not have name, how do i identify it then

Comment: If the volume is bound, then all we get for the volume name is "bind".  For bound volumes, how can we discover the link between volume and container?