# Make Docker Swarm use same volumes from Docker-Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file with some services:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
    # PostgreSQL
    db:
        image: postgres:12
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

    # MongoDB Server
    mongo:
        image: mongo:4.2
        volumes:
            - mongo_data:/data/db
            - mongo_data:/data/configdb

volumes:
    mongo_data:
    mongo_config:
    postgres_data:
```

I've been working in production starting the services with `docker-compose up -d`. But now I want to use `docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml mystack` for future scalability.

The problem is that the services are now using **new** volumes. So I can't use all the DB data. How could I make Swarm to use the existing `docker-compose` volumes?

Any kind of help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Kiryl pointed out, the answer was the [external volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external) but there were several steps to follow, which I list below:

1. Inspect the containers to get the volumes they're using and get their names. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35311469/7058363) indicates how to do that.
2. Edit the `docker-compose.yml` file to add the `external` key with the name of the *existing* volumes. The result was as follows:

```yaml
volumes:
    mongo_data:
        external:
            name: existing name...
    mongo_config:
        external:
            name: existing name...
    postgres_data:
        external:
            name: existing name...
```

3. Start with `docker-compose up -d` to check that all the volumes are OK. Then shutdown with `docker-compose down`
4. Deploy the stack with `docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml mystack`

Also, there's [the same question in the official Docker Forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/make-docker-swarm-use-same-volumes-from-docker-compose/99820/2) where there are other valuable solutions and opinions.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [external volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external)

Comment: Thank you! I'll write an answer listing all the steps I've made to solve the problem

Comment: Sure :) Glad it helped